# Distinct table using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table like this:

```
+----+-------+------------------+
| ID | Name  | TipoContenedorID |
+----+-------+------------------+
|  1 | first |               10 |
|  2 | two   |                9 |
|  3 | three |               10 |
+----+-------+------------------+
```

So depending of `"TipoContenedorID"` I get the name of another table with anonymous type like this:

```
 var vehiculo = _pService.Listar(x => x.TipoContenedor.CatalogosID.Equals("TCO"), includeProperties: "TipoContenedor").Select(x => new
                {
                    x.TipoContenedor.ID,
                    x.TipoContenedor.Nombre
                });
```

Problem is I just want to receive value one time. Actually I get:

```
TipoContenedor.Nombre = firstname
TipoContenedor.Nombre= secondname
TipoContenedor.Nombre = firstname
```

So I'm getting the first name twice. How do I distinct that `TipoContenedorID` if repeated just pass it? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [.Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var vehiculo = _pService
    .Listar(x => x.TipoContenedor.CatalogosID.Equals("TCO"), includeProperties: "TipoContenedor")
    .Select(x => new
            {
                x.TipoContenedor.ID,
                x.TipoContenedor.Nombre
            })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged `entity-framework`, how about changing the link from `Enumerable.Distinct` to [`Queryable.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456(v=vs.110).aspx) and removing the *See also ...* which has nothing to do here.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I thought about that but there is no translatable extension method for EF named `Listar` *although maybe they wrote their own*. I have updated per your suggestion.

Comment: You are right, sorry - with these repositories one never know what they return :)